# How to pass a selected dropdown value to the MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cascadingdropdown

This is the AJAX method and MVC Controller.
The dropdownlist is in the url "http://localhost:1424/home/drop". so after navigating, i choose a state from the dropdownlist and then When I navigate to the url "http://localhost:1424/home/GetStates", the json data is null. the JSON i get on the url is {"selectedCountyId":null}. Please assist.!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
  $('.ddlCountry').change(function () {
        $('#ddlState').empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType:"json",
            url: "Home/GetStates",
            data: { Id: $('.ddlCountry').val() },
        });
    });




 public ActionResult GetStates(string Id)
    {

        return Json(new { selectedCountyId = Id }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Could you put a breakpoint on the controller method to determine if the Id parameter has a value?

Comment: Your use of `$('.ddlCountry')` suggests you might have multiple elements with `class="ddlCountry"`? Or do you mean `$('#ddlCountry')`? And it should be `data: { Id: $(this).val() },` to ensure your referring to the correct element. Also use `url: '@Url.Action("GetStates", "Home")',` to ensure your url's are correctly generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are using class selector, so may be it is finding multiple elements in the DOM.

Also i would advise you to use `Url.Action` to generate urls, don't string this way as url they will cause you trouble in future.

Modify your jquery code to :

```
$('.ddlCountry').change(function () {
        $('#ddlState').empty();
        var selected = $(this).val(); // get current dropdown element selected value
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType:"json",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetStates","Home")',
            data: { Id: selected  },
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data: JSON.stringify({ Id: $('.ddlCountry').val() }),
```

Also make sure your `dropdown` has the `class ddlCountry`.  If this is `id` of your `dropdown` than you need to get `value` by `id` like this.

```
data: JSON.stringify({ Id: $('#ddlCountry').val() }),
```

Comment: Not necessary at all, and if your did use it, then the `contentType` option also needs to be set.